# Checking if Word has terminated correctly

Tags: c#, word-automation

I'm automating a Word document from a WPF application in C#.

In the application I create a Word object with

```
_applicationWD = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

and I terminate it with

```
_applicationWD.Quit(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

Everything is neatly put in try/catch statements. As Quit is the last thing that can go wrong, I need to check if the Quit statement succeeded and then try to terminate it in some other way, otherwise I will have a lot of WinWord.exe in the process list.

Is there any way to check if Word closed or maybe get the PID of the process and force it to terminate from code?

Answer (score 2):

this should kill all the **winword** processes

```
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("WinWord");
            foreach (var myproc in procs)
                myproc.Kill();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Good suggestion, one issue though there could be other instances of word opened by the user instead of by the application , i cant terminate them. I need to find out which process my application starts and terminate it.

Comment: `_applicationWD.Quit(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);` then add `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_applicationWD);`